# Insert multiples values of dict into db

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict(16) 
    ['zone'] => str(3) "S/Z"
    ['name'] => str(20) "John user"
    ['country'] => str(3) "AGO"
    ['date1'] => str(10) "2012-04-23"
    ['date2'] => str(10) "1970-06-24"
    ....
```

---

```
 def save(self):
         insert_client = db.insert('clients', zone = dict.get('zone'), ...)
```

The only way that I know is, with a basic insert, and then iterate the dictionary to make N updates for N items in dict.

```
for key, val in dictionary.iteritems():
    update_client = db.update('clients', key = val)
```

Any idea to make the insert more nice to work? Or should i use the basic insert and then complete the client profile with updates?

PS: the keys of python dict are the column name of database,

Comment: I think your method is fine. Are you asking for other methods? What module is this?

Comment: @aIKid, if this can be done only with a single insert, it will be better. pygresql

Comment: What interface are you using to communicate with MySQL? The only one I am familiar with is MySQLdb, and that doesn't have an insert method. Its obviously possible, an insert method that only inserts a single column isn't worth writing, so what you need is the documentation for that interface/driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `**` (keyword argument unpacking) ?

```
insert_client = db.insert('clients', **dict)
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

Comment: **dict is the equivalent of zone = dict.get('zone'), name = dict.get('name'), and so on? thanks

Comment: @user455318, You're right. See [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from tutorial.